# How to display textile in textview based on onItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to display a text-file  from res/raw into a textview with an onItemSelectedListener.

I can do this hardcoding but it would not be efficient because I have 10+ text-files. So I am trying to optimize my code and display the text-file based the index, which reads from the JSON file. However, when I tried this, nothing displays in the textviews and no errors are being thrown. It just says that the file cannot be found.

```
spSongs.onItemSelectedListener =
                        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                            override fun onItemSelected(
                                adapterView: AdapterView<*>,
                                view: View,
                                i: Int,
                                l: Long
                            ) {

                                songIndex = i  //remember what the user chooses

                                try {
                                    var x = myJSON_array.getJSONObject(songIndex)
                                        .getString("filename")
                                    x = x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf("."))
                                    val temp = resources.getIdentifier(
                                        x,
                                        "raw",
                                        packageName
                                    )
                                    val input_stream =
                                        baseContext.resources.openRawResource(temp)
                                    val text = input_stream.readBytes()
                                        .toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
                                    tvlyrics.text = text

                                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                                //end of try-catch for painting JSON decode
                            }//end of onItemSelected of Painting spinner

                            override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>) {}
                        }// end of setOnItemSelectedListener
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I was calling the wrong array inside the object.